# Access array values - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Hello I have array of friends `this.venner`

[image]

also I have array called `this.convensations` and output is like `this.venner`, 
but id here is called `partner_id` (partner_id output is 54312, 54345, 54346 )

now I want compare if `this.convensation partner_id` and `this.venner id`  if is same

something like this:

```
if (this.convensation in this.venner) {
  //do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

If you wrap that in it's own `checkExistsInArray` function...

```
function checkExistsInArray(arr, compareObj){
  return arr.some(function(obj){ 
    return compareObj[Object.keys(compareObj)] === obj[Object.keys(compareObj)];
  });
}
```

... then you should be able to use that for both arrays by passing in a custom compare object.

```
var friendExists = checkExistsInArray(this.venner, { id: this.friend });

var conversationExists = checkExistsInArray(this.conversations, { partner_id: this.friend });
```

**Side Note** : As others have pointed out, there are libraries out there to readily do this sort of thing. Two of the main players I'm aware of are [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). Even if you choose not to use them, it can sometimes be helpful to see how they work under the hood when looking for a little bit of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter,

```
var result = this.venner.filter(t=>t.id === '54312');
if (result.length >0) {
  //do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, please see, if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can solve this using [Undescore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#find)  _.find function

```
if (.find(this.friend, {"id":this.venner) {
  //do something
} else {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my question, see if you can help me.

Comment: can you comment your arrays

Comment: here is screenshot of my first array (this.venner) and second array this.convensations is like this.venner but id here called "partner_id"